# Restrict logical negation

Tags: logic

Let be:

```
p: is A a rational number.

Not p: A is not a rational number.
```

Hence, A can be a tree, the moon, etc...

But I would like to obtain something like this:

```
p: A is a rational number.
Not p: A is an irrational number.
```

Now:

```
p: A is a number and A is a rational number
Not p: A is not a rational number or A is not a number.
```

In this case A still can be a tree or the moon.

In general, does the negation of a sentence like "X is Y" always implies that "X" can be everything in the universe except Y?

How do we restrict a negation so it includes only a subset of the universe?

I mean in the sense expressed above. I know that the negation of "X is not Y" gives that "X is Y".

Comment: You might find this useful: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Many-sorted_logic

Comment: There’s a bit of rhetorical trickery going on here. In terms of “restricting a logical negation”, it’s not too tricky to include an additional predicate domain and to define the outcome of an operation relative to that domain. However, you’re defining a new operation - what comes out doesn’t have the same logical force as *Negation as such*. This is important to appreciate when considering the application of logical methods, because it risks invoking distribution fallacies (https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Categorical_proposition#Distributivity)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First one defines the **universe of discourse**, i.e. one defines the set A of all elements to be considered.

Then one can define **propositions** about the universe of discourse: For example „All elements from A satisfy property P“. The proposition negates as „There exists at least one element of A which violates property P.“

Your example: A = the set of real numbers. P = the property of being rational.